# I have integrated CLIPS with VC++(MFC), why there are some function does't execute,such as "strcmp"

Tags: c++, mfc, integration, clips

I used the CLIPS6.30 version, and the way that I embeded the CLIPS into VC++ was just like the wrappedDLLExample shown in "advance.doc" (using CLIPSWind32.lib and CLIPSWin32CPP.lib).

When I write a class myCLIPSCPPRouter, I need to compare the logicalNames.But the function "strcmp" doesn't work. The code line was skipped.

```
int myCLIPSRouter::Query(CLIPSEnv *cEnv,char *logicalName)
{
    int n = strcmp(logicalName,m_lName); //Line (1)
    if(strcmp(logicalName,m_lName) == 0)
        return TRUE;
    else 
        return FALSE;
 }
```

The line (1) will always be shipped. And no matter these two strings (logicalName and m_lName)are the same or not, it goes to the end of the function, ie.the "strcmp()" isn't executed. So wierd*!(I wrote "it goes to 'return FALSE' formerly.it was wrong.")*
And there is no error with these two strings. I have changed the both to "abc", and doesn't make a difference.

I have tried other method,like transforming the char* to CString, and then invoking str.compareNoCase().But it's skipped too.

I think maybe the way that I use the CLIPSRouter is wrong. I just want to make the message that CLIPS  "printout" can be displayed on the editbox of a Dialog.If you are familliar with CLIPS integration, please tell me the right way. Thank you very very very much!!!!

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have just tried return TRUE directly, there's also nothing displayed in the editbox.Maybe the problem is that  I haven't really understood the use of the class CLIPSCPPRouter. Thank you once more.

Comment: I think you are referring to my comment which I deleted it after I realized it's not helpful. Maybe put `TRACE("%s,%s\n", logicalName, m_lName)` in to `Query` and put break points on return statements. I don't know anything about this device, but it's strange that `strcmp` shouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you again. The lib I used is released version, so the projec must be builded to released version too. Building to a debug version will throw errors. The TRACE command will be omitted in the released version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a beta version of CLIPS 6.30 rather than the release version (clips_windows_projects_630.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.30/). The DLL doesn't expose the router functionality, so it's unclear how you could get your code to compile if you're embedding CLIPS in the same manner as the WrappedDLLExample.

The following code demonstrates how to set up a simple print router when using the SimpleLibExample. It surrounds each string of text to be printed within <> so that you can easily see it's being invoked:

```
#include "clipscpp.h"

using namespace CLIPS;

static char *m_lName = "abc";

class myCLIPSRouter : public CLIPSCPPRouter
  {   
   public:
      virtual int Query(CLIPSCPPEnv *,const char *);
      virtual int Print(CLIPSCPPEnv *,const char *,const char *);
  };

int main()
  {
   CLIPSCPPEnv theEnv;
   myCLIPSRouter theRouter;

   theEnv.AddRouter("myRouter",100,&theRouter);
   theEnv.Build("(defrule hello"
                "   =>"
                "  (printout abc \"Hello World.\" crlf)"
                "  (printout abc \"Hit return to end.\" crlf)"
                "  (readline))");
   theEnv.Reset();
   theEnv.Run(-1);

   return 0;
  }

int myCLIPSRouter::Query(CLIPSCPPEnv *cEnv,const char *logicalName)
{
    int n = strcmp(logicalName,m_lName); 
    if(strcmp(logicalName,m_lName) == 0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
 }

int myCLIPSRouter::Print(CLIPSCPPEnv *cEnv,const char *logicalName,const char *output)
{
    printf("<%s>",output);
    return 1;
}
```

The same code can also work with the WrappedDLLExample, but the router APIs need to be exposed in the DLL. There are code updates to do this checked in the SVN repository here: http://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/microsoft_windows/Source/Integration/. You'll need to recompile the DLL and libraries (CLIPSDynamic, CLIPSStatic, and CLIPSWrapper Projects in the CLIPS Solution).

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's really helpful!  I have use the CLLPSRouter the same way you shown above. And thanks to you, I know this part of my project is right. Then I began to find the bug in other part. Finally, I find the problem is in the "hello.clp" which is the same one used in the WappedDLLExample. I comment the code `(readline)`, then I can get the `Hit return to end` in my editbox.  Thank you once more. // By the way, I don't what's the version of the CLIPS6.3 I have used.

Comment: But the CLIPSRouter is availible. I want to show you the link that I used to download the CLIPS, but I couldn't find it any more. I remember that I have download a file named "clipsmm", after unzip, I got 8 subfiles:BTC2006, CLPSJNI, Documentation, FeatureTests, Integration Examples, Libraries, MVC2008, Source. I recompiled the project, then used the libraries. I don't know if there's problems with this version. Do I need to download the updated one?

Comment: I am sorry to have to inflict myself upon you. I just have remembered that the first time I compiled my code which invoked the CLIPSCPPRouter class , there were many errors numbered  [LNK2001] displayed in the output window. I thought I might miss loading some resource files, and I didn't know which one was lost. So, I loaded all the files in the folder "../Integration" and " ../libraries". That means I actually used the same manner as the SimpleLibExample. That's why I could get my code to compile successfully. Thank you for your answering and source code updating,from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: You probably downloaded the code from the clipsmm project repository on SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/p/clipsmm/code/ci/master/tree/clips/. That's a copy of the CLIPS source code from six years ago. I would recommend using a newer version of the source code from the CLIPS project itself: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/.